# Unexpected type(s): (set[Selfcheckout | int]) Possible type(s): (SupportsKeysAndGetItem) (Iterable[tuple[Any, Any]])

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a `Unexpected type(s): (set\[Selfcheckout | int\]) Possible type(s): (SupportsKeysAndGetItem) (Iterable\[tuple\[Any, Any\]\])` error.

`Lane` is a normal counter, and `Self` is a self checkout both have an attribute in the form of queue which is just a list of customers.

I'm trying to sort this list of `Lanes` and `Self`s called `openqueues` using a dictionary.

I don't really have an idea what to do next, this function is just supported to return the sorted list of lanes basted on their lengths.

```py
def getsortedopen(openqueues):
    sort = []
    dictionary = {}
    if isinstance(openqueues, list):
        for lane in openqueues:
            if isinstance(lane, Lane) | isinstance(lane, Self):
                dictionary.update({lane, len(lane.queue)})
        dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        dictionaryb = dict(dictionary)
        for key in dictionaryb:
            sort.append(key)
```

Comment: `{lane, len(lane.queue)}` is a set. You probably meant `dictionary.update({lane: len(lane.queue)})` (note colon not comma). But it's simpler to replace that with `dictionary[lane]=len(lane.queue)` .

Comment: The function should be implementable in a 1-liner: `return sorted(lane for lane in queues if isinstance(lane, (Lane | Self)), key=lambda l: len(l.queue))`

Comment: also, `|` is not "or".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes needed:

```
def getsortedopen(openqueues):
    sort = []
    dictionary = {}
    
    if isinstance(openqueues, list):
        for lane in openqueues:
            if isinstance(lane, Lane) or isinstance(lane, Self):
                dictionary[lane] = len(lane.queue)
        
        # Sorting the dictionary by the length of the queues
        sorted_dict = dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
        
        # Appending the lanes to the result list
        sort.extend(sorted_dict.keys())
    
    return sort
```

1. Use or instead of | for logical OR.
2. Use {} to create a dictionary.
3. Simplify the sorting and appending process.